# Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for gradle glibc 2.14 via Jenkins not working

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

We use a Rhel6 as our build machine for all types of projects (Android, Windows, IOS). The machine has glibc version 2.12 installed. Due to some reasons we can't use glibc version 2.14 for all projects. We need to use it only in one Android project where we have upgraded our build tools to version 26.0.2, which will fail without glibc 2.14.

By looking at some of the solutions, we decided to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH through EnvInject plugin in Jenkins. As soon as we export this variable, gradle build does not work at all. It gets stuck at the beginning.

Anyone else faced this issue? How to use glibc version 2.14 only for one project and continue using glibc version 2.12 in other projects?

thank you.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: The only solution I found is this link.

[link](http://nkey.de/post/einfach-mal-die-android-build-tools-auf-centos-6-fixen/)